# Can you run Windows off an external SSD via USB-C?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, boot-camp, usb-c

I have a 2017 Touchbar Macbook Pro, so has 4 USB-C Thunderbolt 3 ports.

Rather than running bootcamp and splitting my inbuilt SSD drive into a MacOS partition and a Windows partition, I am considering getting this SATA-to-USB-C combination:

- [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B072R78B6Q/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B072R78B6Q) or [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B073SBZ8YH/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073SBZ8YH)
- [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0133F30R8/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0133F30R8)

Or simply a direct USB-C drive:

- [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B078SWJ3CF/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B078SWJ3CF)

Then to install Windows 10 onto the drive, and boot into it from my Macbook.

Is this possible?

Comment: The Mac wouldn't mind, but Windows doesn't like booting from external drives. You'd need WinToGo

Comment: have you tried Windows To Go?

Answer (score 2):

This is called [Windows To Go](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview), but this is officially only supported for Windows 10 Enterprise edition.

If you use the normal Windows 10 Home or Pro edition, setup a Windows 10 VM (if you are on Mac) and use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create a [Windows To Go drive](http://www.intowindows.com/rufus-to-create-windows-to-go-usb-drive/):

[image]

Now boot from that SSD connected via USB(-c) and use Windows.

Comment: Great thank you! I am wondering though... whether or not the sata to usb-c connection will treat the drive more as an internal drive than a usb drive. If not, fair enough.

Comment: I don't have an USB-C cable/enclosure, but normal USB3 one and drive and it is found as USB device.